# AngularJS: Ng-click passes parameter into correct Ng-show

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, modal-dialog

I have an app with several modals on the page.  What I'd like to do is have only one controller function that toggles the visibility of the modals.  So, let's say I have the following:

```
<a href ng-click="openModal(modal1)></a>
<a href ng-click="openModal(modal2)></a>
```

Then I'd like the modals to have something along the lines of:

```
<div class="modal" ng-show="openModal(modal1)">
<div class="modal" ng-show="openModal(modal2)">
```

Hope this is clear.  I'm new to angular so kind of lost on this one.  I know I can set a bunch of functions that toggle the boolean of that specific modal type, but then my controller would get big pretty fast.  I'd like to keep it as concise and clean as possible.  Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Why do you need "one controller function"? One "one"? Can you elaborate a bit on the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: My bet is you really only need one modal and the content can be set based on which item is clicked. Not enough detail provided to help much though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angular.module('ngToggle', [])
.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.custom = true;
    $scope.toggleCustom = function() {
        $scope.custom = $scope.custom === false ? true: false;
    };
}]);
```

Use ng-toggle and do an ng-toggle. It works on-click and you'll just need to set the property for each modal and then pass it in. So, something like..

```
$scope.modal1visibility = true;
$scope.modal2visibility = false;
```

Then you should just be able to pass in those individual properties to the toggle functions and that should do what you're wanting it to do. Hope I understood your question and that this helps

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2806-creating-a-simple-modal-system-in-angularjs.htm this link looks like it might be what you're talking about. I think I may have misunderstood after some further looking..